# Do I have to list all of the previous employment information in the DS-160 visa form?

Tags: visas, usa

My dad and I are filling out the DS-160 Visa form online. We got to where he is asked to list all of his previous employment. The problem is that he has worked in a lot of schools in the past 25 years. Would it matter, and would he risk rejection, if he didn't list all of his employment on the form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The DS-160 FAQ [says](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/forms/ds-160--online-nonimmigrant-visa-application/frequently-asked-questions.html)

> enter information regarding your **previous two employers only**.

However, same FAQ elaborates that

> Applicants may choose to bring along a separate written list of all previous employers to the visa interview for reference.

Answer (score 3):

He should list as many as he remembers. Do not fret over those he does not remember. The USA is primarily concerned with working for or affiliation with terror sponsoring organizations, criminal enterprises, and terrorist organizations. He will not be refused because he worked for some school twenty years ago for a few months and forgot to include it.

How do I know? Because during my green card and citizenship process I forgot some minor companies I briefly worked for and it was not a problem. Note that green card and citizenship applications are scrutinized even more stringently than visa applications.

Answer (score 2):

DS-160 FAQ mentions about previous employers in last 5 years.

```
For US employers, It's better to put those details where one worked with valid work petitions, tax/W2 history.

For Non-US employers in last 5 years, it's better to put that information, if available.
```

Few Non-USCIS website to substantiate above info:
Few non-USCIS websites supporting above information is as :

[Immihelp - DS160 - Previous Employment - Details](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/ds-160-form/previous-work-education-training-information.html)

[Immihelp - DS160 - Previous Employment - Discussion Forum](http://www.immihelp.com/forum/showthread.php/158049-DS-160-previous-employment-question)

Comment: substantiate with the link to the original data, please. The official FAQ, linked above, does not have the information you quoted

Comment: @mzu, I could not find a link that substantiates above information on USCIS website, however I have been working in the USA for the past 11 years on non-immigrant visa with many times filing DS-160 form with above details. Few non-USCIS website links are added to substantiate the info above.